# pre-hiding element the most accessible way

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, rendering, visibility

I got a dilemma.

My objective is to reduce the amount of repainting and reflowing that has to be done to render the page. So far, I've achieved alot by following this kind of code format:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>whatever</title>
</head>
<body>
<div ID="page">
<!-- All visible page content and normal HTML here -->
</div>
<script>
document.getElementById('page').style.visibility="hidden";
// functions to manipulate dom and styles of elements go here
document.getElementById('page').style.visibility="visible";
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

So far, this format works fine with all browsers including Internet Explorer 7. I however see some issues.

When the page is processed (especially in slow motion), the full page renders without the styles applied loads, then the whole page goes white while the javascript executes, then after execution, the page returns with styles applied.

Now what I want to do is make it where those users with javascript enabled will see the page blank until everything is done then show everything all at once. I'm trying to minimize repainting and reflowing (as I want to do everything behind the scenes).

Here's what I thought of and tried so far to no success:

Code #1:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>whatever</title>
<style>
#page{visibility:hidden}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div ID="page">
<!-- All visible page content and normal HTML here -->
</div>
<script>
// functions to manipulate dom and styles of elements go here
document.getElementById('page').style.visibility="visible";
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This code won't work because users who have CSS enabled and javascript disabled will see a blank screen when the page loads. I want ALL users to see content regardless of the browser or settings used.

Code #2:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>whatever</title>
<script>
var x=document.getElementsByTagName("STYLE")[0];
if(x){
    x.innerHTML+="#WR{visibility:hidden}";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div ID="page">
<!-- All visible page content and normal HTML here -->
</div>
<script>
// functions to manipulate dom and styles of elements go here
document.getElementById('page').style.visibility="visible";
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This acts up in Internet Explorer 7 when it comes accross innerHTML. It states:

> Line: 1
>   Char: 55
>   Error: Unknown runtime error
>   Code: 0

Then I tried this code.

Code #3:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>whatever</title>
<script>
var x=document.getElementById("WR");
if(x){
    x.style.visibility="hidden";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div ID="page">
<!-- All visible page content and normal HTML here -->
</div>
<script>
// functions to manipulate dom and styles of elements go here
document.getElementById('page').style.visibility="visible";
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Internet Explorer 7 reports:

> Line: 1
>   Char: 1
>   Error: Object doesn't support this property or method
>   Code: 0

I tried changing `document.` to `window.` and I still receive the above error. If I removed the prefix and just used `getElementById("WR")`, then I get an Object Expected error from IE7.

Is there anything I can do to fix this so that as many web browsers as possible (new and old) with javascript enabled can see the whole screen blank and when the javascript has finished processing, the screen reappears?

Also, I want to limit the amount of javascript between `<head>` and `</head>` because I have adsense ads on my site and I don't want their code too low in my HTML and also I want my pages to load quick.

Comment: getElementById - lowercase d.

Comment: You're right about that but that doesn't completely solve the issue. I just have a habit of using capital ID when typing getelementbyid in to make ID stand out.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the special code for ie7 like so

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // this is only executed for IE 7
  </script>
<![endif]-->
```

put this inside the head.then find the fix for ie 7 with this issue and place it here

Hope this helps